# Creating JSONObject from string in JAVA (org.json)

Tags: java, android, json

I'm using the org.json and I have that JSON in a string:

> {"hours":["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11"]}

When I try to create a new JSONObject from that string, I'm getting the following error:

```
Value of type ..String cannot be converted to JSONObject.
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** assuming str has the content:

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(str);
```

**EDIT2:** Here's the real string:

```
{"hours":["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11"],"lessons":["\u05d2\u05d9\u05d0,\u05ea\u05dc\u05de,\u05e2\u05e8\u05d1,\u05e4\u05d9\u05e1,\u05d1\u05d9\u05d5,\n\u05d6\u05d9\u05d5,\u05d5\u05d9\u05d9,\u05dc\u05d5\u05d9,\u05e4\u05d1\u05dc,\u05e8\u05d9\u05d9,","\u05d2\u05d9\u05d0,\u05ea\u05dc\u05de,\u05e2\u05e8\u05d1,\u05e4\u05d9\u05e1,\u05d1\u05d9\u05d5,\n\u05d6\u05d9\u05d5,\u05d5\u05d9\u05d9,\u05dc\u05d5\u05d9,\u05e4\u05d1\u05dc,\u05e8\u05d9\u05d9,","\u05d7\u05e0\"\u05d2 \u05d1\u05e0\u05d9\u05dd,\u05d7\u05e0\"\u05d2 \u05d1\u05e0\u05d5\u05ea\n\u05d9\u05de\u05e4\u05d5\u05dc\u05e1\u05e7\u05d9 \u05dc,\u05e0\u05d0\u05d5\u05e8 \u05de\u05dc\u05d9","\u05e1\u05e4\u05e8\u05d5\u05ea\n\u05d6\u05d9\u05dc\u05d3\u05de\u05df \u05d0\u05d5\u05e8\u05dc\u05d9","\u05d0\u05e0\u05d2\u05dc\u05d9\u05ea\n\u05d1\u05e9\u05d9 \u05e9\u05d5\u05dc\u05de\u05d9\u05ea","\u05d0\u05e0\u05d2\u05dc\u05d9\u05ea\n\u05d1\u05e9\u05d9 \u05e9\u05d5\u05dc\u05de\u05d9\u05ea","\u05ea\u05e0\",\u05e2\u05e8\u05d1,\u05e6\u05e8\u05e4,\u05e7\u05d5\u05dc,\u05d1\u05d9\u05d5,\n\u05e9\u05d7\u05e3,\u05de\u05d6\u05dc,\u05dc\u05e1\u05e7,\u05d8\u05d5\u05e4,\u05dc\u05d5\u05d9,","\u05ea\u05e0\",\u05e2\u05e8\u05d1,\u05e6\u05e8\u05e4,\u05e7\u05d5\u05dc,\u05d1\u05d9\u05d5,\n\u05e9\u05d7\u05e3,\u05de\u05d6\u05dc,\u05dc\u05e1\u05e7,\u05d8\u05d5\u05e4,\u05dc\u05d5\u05d9,","\u05e2\u05e8\u05d1,\u05e7\u05d5\u05dc,\u05d1\u05d9\u05d5,\u05d8\u05db\",\u05e8\u05d5\u05e1,\n\u05dc\u05d5\u05d9,\u05e7\u05de\u05d7,\u05d1\u05e1\u05d5,\u05d5\u05e7\u05e1,\u05e6\u05d5\u05e8,","\u05e2\u05e8\u05d1\u05d9,\u05e7\u05d5\u05dc\u05e0,\u05d1\u05d9\u05d5\u05d8,\u05d8\u05db\"\u05dd\n\u05dc\u05d5\u05d9,\u05d1\u05e1\u05d5\u05df,\u05d5\u05e7\u05e1,\u05e6\u05d5\u05e8",""]}
```

**EDIT3:** Finally, here's my code, hopefully you can fix that problem.

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://ohel-shem.com/~iApplication/appdata.php?pass=12345&request=cp&day=4%20&class=7&layer=12");
        Log.d("MyTag","Before");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

//       Get the response
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader
          (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
          str.append(line);
        } 
        Log.d("MyTag","hello");
        String s = str.toString();
                s= s.replaceAll("\n", "\\n");
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(s); //Occures an error converting string to jsonobject
```

Comment: does your code actually have the curly bracket at the end?  obviously not as that wouldn't compile.

Comment: Did you forget to include the new key word? if you forget the new keyword then the compiler would think you are just casting it to a JSONObject which would be illegal.

Comment: That's exactly how it is written (editted my question)

Comment: paste the string assignment please.

Comment: @MikePatel The string is not really the same as I mentioned, I'll upload it in a minute.

Comment: @MikePatel This is the real string(I gain from the server)

Comment: the newlines ( \n ) are breaking it.

Comment: @MikePatel Seriously? How do you recommend me to get these out?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of \n breaking your parser.

\n specifies a newline character, i'm not sure exactly why it breaks the parser but adding a \ to it will espace the control character.

```
@Test
public void test() throws JSONException {

        String s = 
        "{\"hours\":[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\",\"4\",\"5\",\"6\",\"7\",\"8\",\"9\",\"10\",\"11\"],\"lessons\":[\"\u05d2\u05d9\u05d0,\u05ea\u05dc\u05de,\u05e2\u05e8\u05d1,\u05e4\u05d9\u05e1,\u05d1\u05d9\u05d5,\n\u05d6\u05d9\u05d5,\u05d5\u05d9\u05d9,\u05dc\u05d5\u05d9,\u05e4\u05d1\u05dc,\u05e8\u05d9\u05d9,\",\"\u05d2\u05d9\u05d0,\u05ea\u05dc\u05de,\u05e2\u05e8\u05d1,\u05e4\u05d9\u05e1,\u05d1\u05d9\u05d5,\n\u05d6\u05d9\u05d5,\u05d5\u05d9\u05d9,\u05dc\u05d5\u05d9,\u05e4\u05d1\u05dc,\u05e8\u05d9\u05d9,\",\"\u05d7\u05e0\\\"\u05d2 \u05d1\u05e0\u05d9\u05dd,\u05d7\u05e0\\\"\u05d2 \u05d1\u05e0\u05d5\u05ea\n\u05d9\u05de\u05e4\u05d5\u05dc\u05e1\u05e7\u05d9 \u05dc,\u05e0\u05d0\u05d5\u05e8 \u05de\u05dc\u05d9\",\"\u05e1\u05e4\u05e8\u05d5\u05ea\n\u05d6\u05d9\u05dc\u05d3\u05de\u05df \u05d0\u05d5\u05e8\u05dc\u05d9\",\"\u05d0\u05e0\u05d2\u05dc\u05d9\u05ea\n\u05d1\u05e9\u05d9 \u05e9\u05d5\u05dc\u05de\u05d9\u05ea\",\"\u05d0\u05e0\u05d2\u05dc\u05d9\u05ea\n\u05d1\u05e9\u05d9 \u05e9\u05d5\u05dc\u05de\u05d9\u05ea\",\"\u05ea\u05e0\\\",\u05e2\u05e8\u05d1,\u05e6\u05e8\u05e4,\u05e7\u05d5\u05dc,\u05d1\u05d9\u05d5,\n\u05e9\u05d7\u05e3,\u05de\u05d6\u05dc,\u05dc\u05e1\u05e7,\u05d8\u05d5\u05e4,\u05dc\u05d5\u05d9,\",\"\u05ea\u05e0\\\",\u05e2\u05e8\u05d1,\u05e6\u05e8\u05e4,\u05e7\u05d5\u05dc,\u05d1\u05d9\u05d5,\n\u05e9\u05d7\u05e3,\u05de\u05d6\u05dc,\u05dc\u05e1\u05e7,\u05d8\u05d5\u05e4,\u05dc\u05d5\u05d9,\",\"\u05e2\u05e8\u05d1,\u05e7\u05d5\u05dc,\u05d1\u05d9\u05d5,\u05d8\u05db\\\",\u05e8\u05d5\u05e1,\n\u05dc\u05d5\u05d9,\u05e7\u05de\u05d7,\u05d1\u05e1\u05d5,\u05d5\u05e7\u05e1,\u05e6\u05d5\u05e8,\",\"\u05e2\u05e8\u05d1\u05d9,\u05e7\u05d5\u05dc\u05e0,\u05d1\u05d9\u05d5\u05d8,\u05d8\u05db\\\"\u05dd\n\u05dc\u05d5\u05d9,\u05d1\u05e1\u05d5\u05df,\u05d5\u05e7\u05e1,\u05e6\u05d5\u05e8\",\"\"]}";
        s= s.replaceAll("\n", "\\n");
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(s); 
    }
```

works fine.

Edit: looking at your code you are in luck. Some services sometimes add a crazy character to the start of the feed and it looks like this is what happened here. You just need to trim it from the string.

Example :

```
s = s.substring(s.indexOf("{"));
```

Comment: Wow, it is working but when I tried to implement it on my own code, it didn't. I'm going to give you my code, you can't believe how much time I'm stuck on this issue here, I'll be very glad if you would help me.

Comment: It really works for you? I've added that line right after the replace function, and still same issue for me..

Comment: Sorry, it really works, I guess I was just tired or something.. I really thank you deeply I would never guess it was the problem. Can you please explain me why you switch the /n to //n? and why the hell these services add random characters? Again, I'm very thankfull for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JSONTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
        String str = "{\"hours\":[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\",\"4\",\"5\",\"6\",\"7\",\"8\",\"9\",\"10\",\"11\"]}";
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(str);
        System.out.println(jsonObject);
    }
}
```

Output is : `{"hours":["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11"]}`

Comment: Great, it works actually, but can you look at "EDIT 2" (in my question above) that is the real string that I'm trying to convert to jsonobject. Actually if I could conver a stream to a jsonobject it would be much better because I get that string from a server